# How to show a webpage in full screen on all platforms?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, fullscreen

I am trying to show my JSF/Primefaces webpages in full screen mode so the address bar is hidden whenever the page loads.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: That would be a nightmare.

Comment: Imagine a world that every web page that you show can do something like that

Comment: Try in plain html. If you succeed there, you can achieve this in jsf to (jsf is merely an html generator in this regard). But like the others commented... you won't succeed.